# Error 500.21 after deploying ASP.NET Core app locally to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, iis, publishing

I seem to be having noob level errors here Publishing an ASP.NET app locally.

The site is:

- Published to an ApplicationPool with `No Managed Code` per suggestions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis)
- Is literally just [the template code app from Microsoft specified in this article](https://jonhilton.net/2016/12/01/fast-track-your-angular-2-and-net-core-web-app-development/) - no extra stuff.

I'm just trying to test settings here on my local machine before seeing how it works on another machine but perhaps I'm missing something? Everything I've read I can on the subject and simply can't seem to get this going - any step-by-step walkthroughs about doing this?

[image]

Comment: found any answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the answer was staring me right in the face - I was missing the [AspNETCore Module](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core). I thought I had it when enabling everything else with IIS but apparently, I didn't.

Comment: I notice here you make no mention what machine you have it deployed on. Also the download link you specify is that say for windows servers, as I believe an asp.net core apps created with the template would have all the installed modules needed. Yes of course because I downloaded the .Net Core SDK 1.0.4 and it only offers repair as its already on my system so this doesn't fix anything.